# Showing file on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I want have two links that to download and view the files

I am able to download the file directly. If user selects to view option I want to open that file in browser new tab.

How I will do it in asp.net mvc?

For download I have below action

```
public FileResult Document()
        {

           return File(filepath, contenttype,filename);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control whether or not the file opens in a new tab or an existing tab from the server, this is controlled by setting the `target` attribute on the link definition.

You can control whether the browser downloads or attempts to display the file by setting the content type.